# windows jar service is not running after setting up with prunsrv

Tags: java, windows, service, jar

I was using [Appache Commons Deamon](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/download_daemon.cgi)

```
    prunsrv.exe //IS/Service-Test ^
    --DisplayName="ServiceTest" ^
    --DisplayDescription="Executor Service Test" 
    --Install=C:\Selenium\procrun\prunsrv.exe ^
    --Startup=auto ^
    --Jvm="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\server\jvm.dll" ^
    --Classpath=C:\Selenium\Libraries\lib\*;C:\Selenium\ServerTest.jar ^
    --StartMethod=main ^
    --StartMode=jvm ^
    --StartClass=com.vzw.uat.dbbackup.emailTest ^
    --StopClass=com.vzw.uat.dbbackup.emailTest ^
    --StopMode=jvm ^
    --StdOutput=C:\Temp\stdout.log --StdError=C:\Temp\stderr.log ^
    --StopMethod=stop
```

This does create a service but jar does not run.

I have tried following to create service which works but stops after 2 minutes

`sc create ServiceTestJarFile binpath="java.exe -cp C:\Selenium\ServerTest.jar;C:\Selenium\Libraries\lib\* com.vzw.uat.dbbackup.emailTest" start=auto type=own error=ignore`

I also have used https://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/ which works fine but getting it approve through our IT is a headache and takes 2-3 months.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working :)

I was using **32bit prunsrv.exe** instead of **procrun\amd64\prunsrv.exe**

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot the caret at the end of line 3 (`--DisplayDescription`).
The parameter `--DisplayDescription` itself seems to prevent any progress, though. When I removed it, the service got registered.